# How-to extract a region from a ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, regions, data

### Question

How could I extract a surface from the `ListContourPlot` and use it to sample data? Below is the plot, and the code used to generate it. The `GridLines` define the surface of interest.

Please note, the `Outer` function used to generate the data is a bit slow.

### Plot

[image: plot]

### Code

```
ListContourPlot[
 (* Data Specification *)
 Outer[{#1, #2, #1*#2} &, Subdivide[.01, 1, 100], Subdivide[10^4, 2*10^7, 400]] // Flatten[#, 1] &
 
 (* General Configuration *)
 , Frame -> True
 
 , ImageSize -> Medium
 , PlotRangeClipping -> False
 , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}
 
 (* Contour Configuration *)
 , Contours -> {500000, 1200000, 2200000}
 , ContourShading -> (RGBColor /@ {"#a3d977", "#ffeca9", "#ffdf71" ,"#ff8f80"})
 , ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Black}}
 
 (* Annotation *)
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]
 
 (* Region Configuration *)
 , GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black]
 , GridLines -> {{.2, .4}, {10^6, 5*10^6}}
 ]
```

### Edit 1

Given the comments, I thought I'd try and piece together a visual of what I'd like to achieve. In essence, I want to select a surface between (x1, x2) and (y1,y2) respecting the different color bounds within it. I then want to take a random sample from that surface, see image below.

[image]

Comment: By "surface of interest" do you mean the portion of the plot in the rectangle defined by the intersecting grid lines? If "sample data" means plotting values in that region, try an interpolating function of your data.

Comment: If what you want is a random point in the region bounded by the gridlines: `rgn = ImplicitRegion[0.2 < x < 0.4 && 10^6 < y < 5*^6, {x, y}]; RandomPoint[rgn]`; or for 100 points: `RandomPoint[rgn, 100]`. If instead you want to filter a data set to the defined region: `Select[data, Element[#, rgn]&]`

Comment: Given a triplet of values that feeds the ListContourPlot, you may include the legend and use that as a criteria to select relevant points.  For example, say the highest value region in the legend has a value of "x", then Select[someData,#[[-1]]>=x&] will give you the points that are in that region.